# Write byte[] to file and read byte[] from file

Tags: java

I'm writing a byte[] to file and read it. But why the byte[] is different between write and read? Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test{
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        try{
            byte[] Write = "1234567812345678".getBytes();
            byte[] Read = new byte[16];

            File test_file = new File("test_file");
            test_file.mkdir();

            String path = new String(test_file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+"test.txt");
            File test_out = new File(path);
            test_out.createNewFile();

            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(test_out));
            out.write(Write);
            out.close();

            File test_in = new File(path);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(test_in));
            while(in.available()>0)
                in.read(Read);
            in.close();

            System.out.println(Write);
            System.out.println(Read);
        }catch ( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output; the input and output are different:

```
[B@139a55 
[B@1db9742
```

Comment: that's the default `toString()` for arrays

Answer (score 1):

> [B@139a55
>   [B@1db9742

Those are the outputs of printing a `byte[]` - it is a hashcode of the object. It has nothing do to with its actual content.

It only tells you that you are printing two different objects - their content could still be the same.

You should instead print the actual content of the byte array: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: It's a randomly generated hashCode, not the address of the object despite the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a `byte[]` that way you are printing the JVM's object reference, not the contents of the array.

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Write));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Read));
```